# Unable to decrypt password

Tags: php, encryption-symmetric

I have decided recently to use a more secure encrytion for my password. I have no problem encrypting my password, after calling  `mc_encrypt($encrypt)` the method returns an encrypted password.

When doing decryption by calling `mc_decrypt($decrypt)`, the method returns false. As you can see in the `mc_decrypt($decrypt)` method, there is an if statement near the bottom. I cannot get the if statement to pass. Does anyone know what I can change to get `$calcmac!==$mac` to return true? Thanks

```
<?php

    class Encrypt {
    public $encryptionKey = 'xxxxxxx';

    public function __construct() {
    define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', $this->encryptionKey);
    }

    // Encrypt Function
    public function mc_encrypt($encrypt){
        $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $key = pack('H*', $this->encryptionKey);
        $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
        $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
        return $encoded;
    }

    // Decrypt Function
    public function mc_decrypt($decrypt){
        $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt);
        $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
        $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
        $key = pack('H*', $this->encryptionKey);
        $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
        $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
        $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
        if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
        $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
        return $decrypted;
    }

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sorry, **encrypting passwords with a secret stored on the server
>   isn't secure**: If an intruder breaks into your codebase, intruder can retrieve
>   each and any password using your codebase and the stored password 
>   (somewhere in code or your persistent store).

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/), the [Online Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/), provides well prepared documents: [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet), [Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet) and [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet). Have a look!

The way to go is a [salted hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

**How to handle newly created passwords**

- If you create a new password, compute `hash = HashFunction( password, salt )` with a random salt
- Save hash and salt in your database along to the user's ID

**How to verify password**

- Locate the userID's record in your database
- retrieve hash and salt from the record
- Based on the password, that user entered to log in, compute `hash = HashFunction( enteredPassword, salt )`
- Finally, verify if the hash retrieved from store is identical to the one computed.

**Why use a hash operation?**

A hash operation is a so called [trapdoor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function): While you can compute the function easily, it's **hard to compute the reverse function**. 
**Corollary:** It's easy to compute a password-hash from a password, but it's hard to compute the password from the password-hash.

**PHP's hash functions**

These days, PHP's [PBKDF2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) is first choice for password hashes [[Wikipedia on PBKDF2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

If your PHP installation is too old, even salted hashes with `md5()` are better than two-encrypted password. **But only in case definitely nothing else is available!**

**Sample of PBKDF2 usage**

```
function getHashAndSaltFromString( $password ) {

   // choose a sufficiently long number of iterations 
   // ... to make the operation COSTLY
   $iterations = 1000;

   // Generate a random IV using mcrypt_create_iv(),
   // openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() or another suitable source of randomness
   $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

   $hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);

   return array( $hash, $salt );

}
```

**Beautiful side effect of hash usage**

Many websites do restrict the length of passwords to a certain length - quite likely due to the length of the underlying persistent storage [= length of field in a database table].

If you use the hash-based password storage technique, your **users might use passwords of arbitrary length**!

> Since the **hash is of constant length** and you only persist password and
>   salt, the length restriction is superfluous. **Support long passwords in your web-app!**

At an extreme case, you could even allow users to upload a file - e.g. a picture of their home - as a credential [=password].

**Side note on random sources in PHP's MCRYPT functions**

Note, that PHP does provide two sources of randomness `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` and `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`.

- `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` gets its randomness from `/dev/random`
- `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` gets its randomness from `/dev/urandom`

`/dev/urandom` provides random data immediately and non-blocking each time you query it, `/dev/random` might block (take some time to return).

Therefore, *at first sight*, `/dev/urandom` and `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` might be better suited for random number generation. **In fact, it is not!**

`/dev/random` might block request up to a point of time, at which sufficiently much [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) has been collected. Thus `/dev/random` and `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` effectively collects randomness.

> If you need to do **strong crypto operations**, use `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` or
>   `/dev/random`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the good advice! I'll look at using a PBKDF2 hash.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on two-way encryption for passwords. If someone can get the cyphertext, they can usually also get the key to decrypt them.

Instead, you should use hashing or key derivation like blowfish or pbkdf2, those are one-way functions that are designed to be hard to crack.

Please, never ever encrypt passwords this way.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into other types.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.7, you should use the password_comp library which was written by guys involved in PHP and it utilizes BCRYPT which is the strongest algorithm available for PHP as of yet.

It's very simple and easy to use.

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Hash the password simply

```
 $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Verify the given password against the stored password hash

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    /* Valid */
} else {
    /* Invalid */
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, like they say no need to rewrite was has already been written especially when it comes to security and written by the experts.

Comment: salt included, checkout lines 51 - 142.

Comment: No it is optional, $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10)); is the same as $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); as it is the default.